# The specified path, file name, or both are too long. C# Azure Chat bot error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, chatbot

I am trying to upload my Visual Studio code to Azure to update my Chat bot that I have created, but keep getting ther error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Copying file
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
>   to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
>   failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248
>   characters.   Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot     0

I am simply trying to do a single time publish not continuous deployment, but this error is halting my development.

Any help or insight into this problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you read the error? It exactly says what is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path appears to be duplicated several times and suggests your folder structure has been changed or otherwise corrupt.

> obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\
>
> > obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\
> >
> > > obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\
> > >
> > > > obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\
> > > >
> > > > > obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs

I suggest examining your project's folders to make sure they're in the correct place and, if needed, Clean the solution and/or manually delete the obj folder and recompile.